# jsplumb how do I use the straight connector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I want to ask some help,This is my first time to use the jsPlumb...I want to change the connectors by using the straight connector,I tried to read there docs,but I am having difficulties to understand it.How can I change the connector to straight line in the hierarchical chart.?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the documentation links for different types of connectors:

Doc: https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/connectors.html

API: http://www.jsplumb.org/apidocs/classes/Connectors.Straight.html

You can set it in defaults as:

```
jsPlumb.importDefaults({
    Connector: ["Straight"]
});
```

To set additional parameters use:

```
jsPlumb.importDefaults({
    Connector: ["Straight", {stub: 10, gap: 10}] // By default stub and gap are 0
});
```

Comment: can you show me how to implement.I am still new on this plugin,just simple as you can.thank you in advance